# Is there an extension to link a file to another like the .designer files

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is there an extension to easily link a file to another in a VS project? The same way a designer file is linked to another file.

I know i can open include the file in the project then open the project in notepad and change 
the include element to depend on another file like

```
<None Include="Features\ContactTestData.json">
    <DependentUpon>ContactInfo.feature</DependentUpon>
</None>
```

but is there a way to do this through the UI?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if [partial classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) may solve your issue. Which is how the form designers work.

It allows you to have multiple class files with the same name in the same namespace accessible as the same class.

Comment: no i'm after separate files. Basically we use Approval Tests which compares a predefined approved file like a json document with the generated version. I want to include these as a sub file to the actual unit test class so you always know what file belongs to what tests. Like in the LinqToSQL files you have a parent being databasecontext.dbml and the generated child files of databasecontext.cs, databasecontext.dbml.layout and databasecontext.designer.cs. I'm talking about the way these are linked in the project

Comment: I see.  I got too hung up on the designer file part and failed to consider it may be a different file type.